# Python - getting list of numbers N to 0

Tags: python

What's the best way to get a list `[N, N-1, ..., 0]` in python? I have 2 ways in mind

```
>>> range(10)[::-1]
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]

>>> range(9, -1, -1)
[9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Comment: "*best*" is a word with different meanings to different people. What do *you* mean when you say "What's the best way" ?

Comment: I have to iterate over the list and `1<=N<=50000`. Plus there will me almost 100 test cases for the code I use. So I am looking for code which is fast enough to not cause any noticeable delay. I would also like some readability but its not an issue.

Comment: If your code does any work *other* than simply looping, it's very unlikely that `range` speed is going to be an issue.  (Excluding extreme cases like an enormous `range` in Python 2, etc.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
range(N, -1, -1) is better
```

You can see it takes much less time:

```
N = 10000

%timeit range(N+1)[::-1]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 767 ns per loop

%timeit range(N, -1, -1)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 334 ns per loop
```

In `range(N+1)[::-1]`, you are first doing the exact same thing as `range(N, -1, -1)` and then inverting the list, that's why it takes more time.

Comment: Does `better == faster`? OP asks which is *better*. Are there any other characteristics that make this a better choice?

Comment: To me it's also more readable/expressive, but I guess that's subjective.

Comment: @Robᵩ Other than being faster nothing else comes to my mind.

Comment: I'd favour `reversed(range(N))` for readability (as aganders3 said though, that's subjective).

Comment: Looks like `reversed(range(N))` is between the speed of the other two, slightly faster than `range(N+1)[::-1]`. I get 720, 355, 602 ns.

Answer (score 3):

If your list of numbers is potentially large, or if you don't actually need the list, but just something to iterate over the range, you can avoid actually creating a list by using

```
xrange(N, -1, -1)
```

As mentioned by Rob in the comment below, this behavior is the new default under Python 3 (returning a generator rather than an actual list), but for Python 2, you have `range()` that returns a list and `xrange()` that returns a generator.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that `range()` in Python3 also returns a generator.

Comment: @Robᵩ Good point... added.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use range, do it like this:

```
range(n, -1, -1)
```

As others shown, it is faster.

Personally, to loop backwards, i prefer using the built-in functions,  `reversed`, combined with `enumerate`:

```
for i, v in enumerate(reversed(mylist))
```

It's a bit more readable,and you get both the index and value :)

Comment: Care to explain the downvote? Woukd be appreciated

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but your answer is subjective, you have not given any evidence as to why either choice is better, and you have based your answer only on your opinions. Also - the OP asked between 2 specific implementations, you ignored one of them, and added one that was not asked about.... Overall - this answer is very low quality.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, inbar. I'll fix it ASAP. I am on mobile.

Answer (score 1):

```
import timeit

print timeit.timeit("range(10)[::-1]", number=10000000)
print timeit.timeit("range(9, -1, -1)", number=10000000)
```

**Output on my machine**

```
2.99922299385
2.24587512016
```

Looks like the second one is slightly faster, so use `range(9, -1, -1)`

Answer (score 0):

Your second method is a touch faster:

```
%timeit range(9,-1,-1)
> 1000000 loops, best of 3: 496 ns per loop

%timeit range(10)[::-1]
> 1000000 loops, best of 3: 659 ns per loop
```